# API request good practice

Tags: api, architecture, dart, mobile-development

I am developing a mobile app, where there is a requests class responsible for sending requests to the server. What is a good practice, to initialize this requests class in the constructor of the classes which access it and then call the functions, or declare the api functions as static so functions can be called with no prior initialization ?

Comment: In the constructor for unit testability / decoupling purposes. Might use more memory though, so it depends on the requirements for your app.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson can you tell me more how it is going to help for better unit testing ?

Comment: When you unit test, you can mock out the "requests" class so that you're not testing it, you're only testing the target/class-under-test. Also you could pass in a different type of "requests" class, and your target class doesn't have to change.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson I got it, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the requests to share instance variables such as an `http.Client` you should prefer the constructor variation. It also makes testing easier as ryanwebjackson said. If they are simply a collection of functions that don't share information then static methods are fine.

If you're worried about instantiating several resource intensive objects, then you could create getters that lazy initialize expensive tasks, e.g.

```
abstract class Request {
  final Client client;
  var _loadsOfData;

  Request(this.client);

  Future get loadsOfData async => _loadsOfData ??= _fetchLoadsOfData();
}
```